# Type hints for matplotlib Axes3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-typing, pylance

I have a function that takes a matplotlib 3D axis:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D


def plot(ax: Axes3D):
    pass
```

I know how to add a type hint for a 2D axis. Just `ax: plt.Axes` works perfectly. However, with this `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D`, pylance complains that:

```
Expected type expression but received (...) -> Unknown Pylance
```

Sadly, there is no `plt.Axes3D` equivalent to `plt.Axes`.

I verified that `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D` works as expected. The following code does not give an error:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
Axes3D(fig)
```

I went to the definition of `Axes3D` and found that the problem is the `@_docstring.interpd` decorator. If I remove it, the pylance warning goes away. The `@_api.define_aliases` seems to be fine.

I am using python 3.10.12 and matplotlib 3.8.0

Edit: The motivation for the type being `Axes3D` and not `Axes` is that otherwise pylance shows a diagnostic that `Axes` has no method `set_zlabel()`, etc.

Comment: What version of vscode are you using?  With v1.82.2, I only see a warning in the import `Stub file not found for "mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d"Pylance(reportMissingTypeStubs)`.  Which is expected, because stub files have not been written for `mpl_toolkits`.

Comment: I used conda environment python 3.10.12 and matplotlib 3.8.0, but I could not reproduce your problem. neither pyright nor vscode pylance extension does not show a problem. please check your error again and give more details if it still exists.

Comment: It seems like it's fixed, maybe in a new version of pylance.

Comment: @Marcel the actual problem might be completely different than what you have given here. I tested older pylance versions up to two months, and could not find such a problem.  one thing you did not mention is the actual number of lines the error belongs, and this "unknown" error might be related to a "call the function without parameters gives unknown" issue/property.